# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '' : failed to load external entity ""

Tags: php, soap, https, openssl, wsdl

Basically when I try to connect to a HTTPS based SOAP web service I receive the error:

`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://webservice.sample.com/ws/' : failed to load external entity "https://webservice.sample.com/ws/"`

I have tried the answers to this error previous and most of them either apply to Windows based servers or don't work in my case.
I am doing this connection on a Linux based server. The code that I am using is

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );

$x509 = new File_X509();
$certfile = file_get_contents('/path/to/cert/file');
$cert = $x509->loadX509($certfile);
$openedcert = openssl_x509_parse($certfile);

$security_requests_array = array();


try {
   $client = new SoapClient('webserviceendpoint', ['trace' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY,'local_cert'=>'/path/to/cert/file']);



   $header = new SoapHeader($security_requests_array);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

print_r($client->__getLastResponse());
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->faultcode,$ex->faultstring,$ex->faultactor,$ex->headerfault);
}
?>
```

I am new to HTTPS based SOAP webservices. So if there is any other information you would like me to provide feel free.

**Edit** The X509.php file is from phpseclib 1.0.1 [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)